# RabbitMQ no ack usage

Tags: c#, node.js, rabbitmq

I'm integrating RMQ into my project, in order to implement work queues.

I understand what if module succeeded, it calls the ack method so RMQ will know about it.

What about failures?

I read that only when connection or channel are closed, RMQ knows we've failed and re-push the message to the queue.

I'd like however to make the RMQ re-push messages whenever I have an internal error, regardless of wheter I crash or not (e.g. failure to insert to DB, I handle that gracefully without crashing however I want the whole job to be re-tried).

Do I have to manually close and open the channel again in order to trigger that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative ACK, or rejects. Info [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html).

> The AMQP specification defines the basic.reject method that allows
>   clients to reject individual, delivered messages, instructing the
>   broker to either discard them or requeue them.

Comment: Missed that. Thanks.